# Получить список коммитов конкретного участника?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

В качестве системы контроля версий используем git. Можно ли как-то получить список всех коммитов конкретного участника? Например, как в gitk для всех, только надо для одного.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --author=<pattern>
```

Подробнее: [gitref.org](http://gitref.org/inspect/)